# Continuous animation problem even if hovered out

Tags: jquery

I have a button that will fade a div upon hover.
If I hover in a button then hover out and repeat that procedure multiple times in quick succession then hover out, the div will go on animating when it should have stopped.
Please refer to the following snippet.

http://jsfiddle.net/arvinboggs/uenEQ/9/

Is there a way to correct this behavior?

Is there a way stop the animation on the final hover out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cut and paste from a previous answer of mine to a similar question:

I actually create a 'state' variable to ensure only 1 action can fire at any time.

What I do is

```
set state = 0; when I initialise the page
check if state == 0 when something is clicked
if it's 0, then I set it to 1 (meaning something's happening)
run the animation
once the animation is complete, I reset the state to 0
```

Effectively, you can only fire the animation event is state == 0 and then there's no overlapping.

---

So to answer your question, when you bind() the hover, it needs to check whether it's allowed to fire the animation or not based on the state setting.

```
var hoverState = 0;
$('.myLink').bind('mouseenter'), function(){
    myHoverCode();
});

function hoverCode(){
  if(hoverState == 0){
    hoverState = 1; // bind this hover state so we can't trigger it again
   // do my animation
  $('#someElement').animate({
},100, function(){
// animation complete
hoverState = 0; // reset the hover state
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Yep. You need to `.stop()` before you `.animate()` again: http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/01/quick-tip-prevent-animation-queue-buildup. Otherwise you build up an animation queue that has to dequeue.

Comment: Does stop let it finish the sequence or "destroy" the event where it's up to? If it stops it in it's tracks, I'd still prefer my "check the state" answer as it allows the sequence to nicely finish.

Comment: @niggles Not entirely sure. I just know that's how every resource I've read (mostly from Sitepoint, to be fair) say to do it. Here's the API reference: [http://api.jquery.com/stop/](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Comment: Looking at the documentation it stops it where it is. A lot of what I've needed it for it MUST get to the finishing point to work with the design e.g a slideshow moving to the correct image in a filmstrip. By binding the thumbnail clicks the big image strip moves to where it should, but doesn't get multiple clicks. stop() would leave it half finished.

Comment: With this solution, I've noticed that when I mouseout midway through the fade animation, the div would remain translucent - something we dont want users to see.